# CSS clip path issue with background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently implementing a switch. The problem is that the background which should be hidden by the switch shows one thin line at the left end. I've absolutely no idea why. The strange thing is that here on SO everything looks really good. The switch is located in a scrollable main wrapper with all the other content. I thought this could be the problem but after removing the scrolling, the error was still there:

[image]

When I run the inspector and hover the element, the background seems to go out:

[image]

This is my code. I've tried a low but can't find the problem:

```js
let toggle = document.getElementById('container');
let toggleContainer = jQuery('#toggle-container');
let toggleNumber;

jQuery('#container').click( function() {
  toggleNumber = !toggleNumber;
  if (toggleNumber) {
    toggleContainer.css( "clip-path", "inset(0 0 0 50%)" );
  } else {
    toggleContainer.css( "clip-path", "inset(0 50% 0 0)" );
  }
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 56px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0.2rem 0.4rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-shadow: 0 0.12rem 0.4rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.inner-container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.inner-container:first-child {
  background: gray;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.inner-container:nth-child(2) {
  background: chartreuse;
  color: #ffffff;
  clip-path: inset(0 50% 0 0);
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.toggle {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  height: inherit;
  display: flex;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.toggle p {
  margin: auto;
}

.toggle:nth-child(1) {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div class="inner-container">
      <div class="toggle">
        <p>Private</p>
      </div>
      <div class="toggle">
        <p>Public</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-container" id='toggle-container'>
      <div class="toggle">
        <p>Private</p>
      </div>
      <div class="toggle">
        <p>Public</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The snippet does not have the problem in Chrome 77 or Firefox 69 on Windows 10. Which browser are you seeing it in?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'n Chrome 77. I'm really confused right now.

Comment: What browser and version? On FF it's working fine. Check compatibility https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @Justinas The lates chrome. Strangely the switch looks good to me in the given example but not within the page...

Comment: This is what I am seeing in your snippet in Chrome: https://i.imgur.com/BY6LJ93.png

Comment: @ThomasByy I've added another image. When I replace inset by rect, I need to change the values too right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest an optimized version with less of code and without the use of `clip-path`:

```js
let toggle = document.getElementById('container');
let toggleContainer = jQuery('.inner-container');

jQuery('#container').click(function() {
  toggleContainer.toggleClass('second');
  });
```

```css
#container {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0.12rem 0.4rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.inner-container {
  height: 56px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: flex;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(chartreuse,chartreuse) left/50% 100% no-repeat,
    gray;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
.inner-container.second {
  background-position:right;
}

.toggle {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.toggle p {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="toggle">
      <p>Private</p>
    </div>
    <div class="toggle">
      <p>Public</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what you are seeing:
Which was done by making the CSS: `clip-path: inset(0 50% 0 1px);`

Maybe just try adding some negative space to the left side:

`toggleContainer.css( "clip-path", "inset(0 50% 0 -10px)" );`

[image]